# WPF - Custom Window not working

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

I am trying to start building a Custom Window in WPF. I thought I had all the starting pieces in place, but so far, all I get is a regular Window with black content. I assume this is because it's not recognizing my template as the default one for the control. 
Can you please let me know what I am missing? Here's my code:

```
namespace BaseWindowLibrary
{
    public class BaseWindow: Window
    {
        public BaseWindow()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(BaseWindow),
                                                     new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                                                        typeof(BaseWindow)));
        }
    }
}


<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:base="clr-namespace:BaseWindowLibrary">

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="BaseWindowTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type base:BaseWindow}">
        <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="3" Background="Coral" Width="100" Height="100"/>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type base:BaseWindow}">
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource BaseWindowTemplate}"/>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you defining this xaml code in `generic.xaml` or in some other resource dictionary and then merging it in `generic.xaml`?

It's a requirement to have the style the default style.

Also, if you have been adding things by hand, check if VS aded the `ThemeInfo` attribute in `AssemblyInfo.cs`.

And if that doesn't work, you should post the code where you declare the window you use (the part in `window.xaml` or whichever name you use).

EDIT

To clarify, generic.xaml MUST be in the Themes folder of your solution and contain (directly or indirectly) the code for the style.

Comment: The xaml code above is the entire content of the xaml file. I don't have a Generic.xaml. Don't I have the default style already? (<Style TargetType="{x:Type base:BaseWindow}">)
Thanks!

Comment: No, the generic.xaml is a predefined location where wpf looks up themes. You must have it in the Themes folder of your solution for default styles to work.

Comment: Just by moving the code to a Themes folder and renaming the file to Generic.xaml didn't do anything... If I copy the entire ControlTemplate code to the Setter.Value it works. Why can't I do Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource BaseWindowTemplate}"?

Comment: Have you tried running the app? Sometimes the designer missess some stuff, but you still get the style applied at runtime.

Comment: Oh yes, Kek, I am trying to run the app.

Comment: I was missing the ThemeInfo attribute in AssemblyInfo.cs - thanks for pointing that out!!!!

Comment: +1 for the ThemeInfo nugget! It does not update when you move the files to a different project.

Comment: The ThemeInfo tip saved me some time

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you havent included the ResourceDictionary in to your application. Add it to the App.xaml

```
   <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="YourResource.xaml" />
   </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

UPDATE based on the comment:
  I tried this BaseWindow:Window as a custom control and it just worked. The Style will be inside Generic.XAML of the custom control library.

Comment: Jobi, the my xaml file contains a resource dictionary. It lives in the custom control, not in my application. This is the template of the control, so the application must not know about it.